# Erro Node App React Native

Tags: node.js, react, react-native

Nao estou conseguindo criar novo projeto react native
Sempre que executo o comando: react-native init MeuProjeto ele não consegue concluir a criação do projeto.

Segue imagem:
[image: Print do erro da criação do projeto]

Answer (score 2):

A versão react-native 0.56.0 tem um bug no windows 10, use a versão 0.55.2.
altere a versão no package.json, limpe a pasta node_modules e execute  npm install, depois é executar.

Answer (score -1):

Instale o yarn, pois ele solicita no inicio da instalação. Existem muitos erros do npm que ocorriam quando usava ele instalar o react native.

Answer (score -2):

Na instalação do Node aparece uma caixa de seleção pra você marcar, aconselho clicar nela que já irá instalar tudo que o React-Native precisa para rodar, após  use o comando de instalação da CLI do React-Native, use o comando npm install -g react-native-cli no prompt de comandos.

Comandos Úteis:

```
react-native init MeuPrimeiroApp (Cria um projeto React Native)
Entre na Pasta do projeto!! ( cd MeuPrimeiroApp )
Abra o Projeto no Visual Studio Code com o comando (Code .)
Volte no mesmo terminal e rode o projeto 
com o comando react-native run-android (Roda o projeto em um dispositivo IOS)
adb devices (Lista Dispositivos conectados)
```

Caso seu celular esteja conectado no PC ele abrirá no celular ou se ele não estiver ele abrirá no emulador.

- O celular precisa estar em modo desenvolvedor.

Feito tudo isso se ainda persistir o erro pode ser algum conflito com o javascript, no Visual Studio Code vá em Arquivo -- Editar ---Configurações, quando aparecer a barra de Pesquisa digite Javascrip, role até aparecer Validação e desmarque a caixa.
Pronto já corrigiu. ;)
Agora é só acelerar!!